# Java Servlet: Retrieve data from remote devices and "push" data to client side by using FTP connection

Tags: java, servlets, ftp

I believe build a small home-made program to make ourselves more comfortable is quite common nowadays. Just few days before, I really tired to get the same named log files from different remote devices through FTP connection again and again so that I started to build one Java web application.

The purpose of the Java web application is simple as once the user filled in the absolute path of source file in remote device and selected corresponding remote devices he or she want to connect to, the web application will finally store those same named log files in user's local computer with well organized folder structure. You can simply understand that this Java servlet is a proxy sits between client and remote devices.

Currently, I have already done and tested the downloading function from remote devices to the server in Java servlet by using Apache common net FTPClient library. It worked fine and provided me the copies of same named log files in a well organized folder structure.

However, when I moved on, I realized that the "pushing" function maybe the killer. Following are few queries I want to discuss with you all:

1. Even I could get IP address or host name from client's requests, is it possible or suitable for me to auto establish a FTP connection from servlet to client?
2. If an auto FTP connection is achievable, what are the security concerns I should pay attention?
3. If an auto FTP connection is not achievable, is it possible or suitable for me to return those files in the response to the client?

I appreciate your comments or suggestions. Hope you all also enjoy the open discussion here.

Comment: Apache FTPserver API may be a good integration for this case. But it also relies on Listener. http://www.slideshare.net/wocommunity/apache-ftp-serverintegration